# ng-select with NGFORM facing rendering issue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngselect

Below is my HTML code, this is where I am trying to use `ng-select` directive as found some where during internet search. As I am not having expertise with me on `ng` I am not sure why the list is not showing on the screen.

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveProfile()"> 
<div class="form-body">
   <h4 class="form-section"><i class="la la-eye"></i> About User</h4>
   <div class="row">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="userinput3">City Selection</label>
         <ng-select [items]="singleSelectArray" [searchable]="true" bindLabel="item_text" placeholder="Select city"
         [(ngModel)]="singlebasicSelected" >
         </ng-select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my TYPESCRIPT File trying to populate city list from server, but in this case I did hard coded from TS file and send to HTML page

```
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('f', { read: true }) userProfileForm: NgForm;
  private profileInfo: DashBoardData.ProfileInfo;
  model: any = {};
  profileInfoFormGroup: FormGroup;
  singleSelectArray = selectData.singleSelectArray;
  cityLoading = false;
  matchedResultArray: City[] = [];

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private dataService: NgSelectDataService) { }

  loadCity() {
    this.cityLoading = true;
    this.dataService.getPeople().subscribe(x => {
      this.matchedResultArray = x;
      this.cityLoading = false;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCity();
  }
}
```

But while rendering on the browser I am getting following error to the `ng-select` component
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular does not have a built-in `ng-select` component. Most likely, you found a piece of [this](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) third-party library on the internet. However, in order to make a drop-down list, it is not needed. You can just use the native browser elements: `select` and `option`.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
    {{ option.title }}
  </option>
</select>
```

I've created an [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gxs71v).

But if you need a more complex dropdown list, for example with a search function, you can install and use this library that I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanx @Markiewic, actually I was applying ngModel to `option` tag that was messed up, but your helpful stakblitz save my time, I appreciate for your killer knowledge... n+1 claps